# How to populate memtables from enumarations?

Tags: delphi, cross-platform, enumeration, delphi-xe6

I use memtables to wire enumerated type with comboboxes using LiveBinding.

However I have a lot of them and they way I am doing is way too bad (copy/paste)

For example, I have the following enumeration:

```
 TEnumResourceType        = (trtApp, trtTab, trtSection, trtField, trtCommand, trtOther);
```

and for that I created a function to give the string equivalent:

```
function EnumResourceTypeToStr(AEnum: TNaharEnumResourceType): string;
begin
  case AEnum of
    trtApp     : result := 'Aplicação';
    trtTab     : result := 'Pagina (Tab)';
    trtSection : result := 'Secção';
    trtField   : result := 'Campo';
    trtCommand : result := 'Comando';
    trtOther   : result := 'Outro';
  end;
end;
```

In a datamodule I place my memtable and I need to populate it, I am using the AFTEROPEN event of the table with the following code:

```
procedure TDMGlobalSystem.vtResourceTypeAfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  enum : TEnumResourceType;
begin
  inherited;

  for enum := Low(TEnumResourceType) to High(TEnumResourceType) do
    DataSet.InsertRecord([EnumResourceTypeToStr(enum), Ord(enum)]);
end;
```

All that works, however I need to do that for each new enumaration and I have dozens. Eventually I will need to change my current memtable to other and that is an added concern to automate the process. The current memtable sometimes does not work on Android.

I am looking in a way to automate this process, or using generics, or whatever, that in the DataModule I only need something like: PopulateEnum(Table, Enum);

The best solution would be creating a component inherited from this memtable and somehow define what is the enum required and all the magic happens (including the selection of the enumtostr)

Comment: Do you only want to fill the table with integers and strings? Why not using a `TDictionary<Integer,String>` for that and to fill the table iterate over the key and get the string for that key?

Comment: If you want to iterate through (nearly) any enum look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379032/using-an-enum-with-generics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic wrapper for enums to get an array of `integer`,`string` pair representing the ordinal value and the name for the enums.

A little test

```
program so_24955704;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  EnumValueStore in 'EnumValueStore.pas';

type
  TEnumResourceType = ( trtApp, trtTab, trtSection, trtField, trtCommand, trtOther );

procedure PrintEnumValueStore( AEnumValueStore : TEnumValueStore );
var
  LEnumValuePair : TEnumValuePair;
begin
  for LEnumValuePair in AEnumValueStore.GetKeyValues do
    begin
      Writeln( LEnumValuePair.Key, '-', LEnumValuePair.Value );
    end;
end;

procedure TestEnum;
var
  LEnumValueStore : TEnumValueStore<TEnumResourceType>;
begin
  LEnumValueStore := TEnumValueStore<TEnumResourceType>.Create;
  try
    // print default names
    PrintEnumValueStore( LEnumValueStore );

    WriteLn;

    // set the custom names
    LEnumValueStore.SetValue( trtApp, 'Aplicação' );
    LEnumValueStore.SetValue( trtTab, 'Pagina (Tab)' );
    LEnumValueStore.SetValue( trtSection, 'Secção' );
    LEnumValueStore.SetValue( trtField, 'Campo' );
    LEnumValueStore.SetValue( trtCommand, 'Comando' );
    LEnumValueStore.SetValue( trtOther, 'Outro' );

    // print the default values
    PrintEnumValueStore( LEnumValueStore );
  finally
    LEnumValueStore.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    TestEnum;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      Writeln( E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message );
  end;
  ReadLn;

end.
```

will produce the following output

```
0-App
1-Tab
2-Section
3-Field
4-Command
5-Other

0-Aplicação
1-Pagina (Tab)
2-Secção
3-Campo
4-Comando
5-Outro
```

and here is the unit that will do the work

```
unit EnumValueStore;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TEnumValuePair = TPair<Integer, string>;

  TEnumValueStore = class abstract
  public
    function GetKeyValues : TArray<TEnumValuePair>; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TEnumValueStore<TEnumKey> = class( TEnumValueStore )
  private
    FValueDict : TDictionary<TEnumKey, string>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SetValue( AKey : TEnumKey; const AValue : string );
    function GetKeyValues : TArray<TEnumValuePair>; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  SimpleGenericEnum;

{ TEnumValueStore<TEnumKey> }

constructor TEnumValueStore<TEnumKey>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FValueDict := TDictionary<TEnumKey, string>.Create;
end;

destructor TEnumValueStore<TEnumKey>.Destroy;
begin
  FValueDict.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TEnumValueStore<TEnumKey>.GetKeyValues : TArray<TEnumValuePair>;
var
  LEnum : TEnum<TEnumKey>;
  LMin, LMax : Integer;
  LCount : Integer;
  LIdx : Integer;
  LStr : string;
begin
  LMin := LEnum.Ord( LEnum.Low );
  LMax := LEnum.Ord( LEnum.High );
  LCount := LMax - LMin + 1;
  SetLength( Result, LCount );

  LCount := 0;
  for LIdx := LMin to LMax do
    begin
      LEnum := LIdx;
      if FValueDict.ContainsKey( LEnum )
      then
        LStr := FValueDict[LEnum]
      else
        LStr := LEnum;
      Result[LCount] := TEnumValuePair.Create( LEnum, LStr );
      Inc( LCount );
    end;
end;

procedure TEnumValueStore<TEnumKey>.SetValue( AKey : TEnumKey; const AValue : string );
begin
  FValueDict.AddOrSetValue( AKey, AValue );
end;

end.
```

I use the unit [`SimpleGenericEnum`](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27397) but there is a small bug inside you need to correct

```
class function TEnum<T>.High: T;
begin
  // original code
  // Result := Cast(_TypeData.MaxValue);
  Result := Cast(GetTypeData.MaxValue);
end;

class function TEnum<T>.Low: T;
begin
  // original code
  // Result := Cast(_TypeData.MinValue);
  Result := Cast(GetTypeData.MinValue);
end;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I will add a method to populate a my standard dataset for representing enum and I am done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would have said you have two easier choices here

Your could replace `EnumResourceTypeToStr(enum)` with `GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TEnumResourceType), ord(enum))` or some variation on it.  This has the disadvantage that it simply returns the enum as it appears in your program.

Alternatively add a constant `EnumNames: array [TEnumResourceType] of string = ('....` etc. populated with your list of strings.  These can then be accessed as `EnumNames[enum]`.  This allows you arbitrary strings and the compiler will remind you to add additional entries if you extend the enumeration.

Comment: +1, your 2nd alternative is easy to maintain and comes with compile time check.

Comment: +1 actually I wanted to define both answers as accepted. Your alternative for hold the strings is very useful, I will be adding this to the other solution and both will solve very well my problem. Thank you for that.